# Can we visit Korea without visa?

Tags: visas, south-korea, applications, filipino-citizens

My husband and I plan to visit Korea, specifically Nami Island, but we're worried that we won't be able to submit all the visa requirements. I am a domestic helper here in Hongkong and my husband doesn't have work. We plan to visit Korea on February 2019 during my vacation. We don't have bank accounts and ITR, so we so what should we do? Is it possible for us to apply for the Korean visa?

My husband and I are both Philippine passport holder.

Answer (score 2):

Philippine-passport holders require a visa to visit South Korea. I am not sure of the application procedure for family members in different locations but I believe you may sponsor your husband on the application. I am not sure whether you need to apply from Hong Kong, the Philippines, or either. Contact the South Korean embassy in Hong Kong or Manila to be sure.

Visa applications made in Manila are required to go through an approved travel agency as stated [here](http://overseas.mofa.go.kr/ph-en/brd/m_3277/view.do?seq=738690&srchFr=&srchTo=&srchWord=&srchTp=&multi_itm_seq=0&itm_seq_1=0&itm_seq_2=0&company_cd=&company_nm=&page=1). A list of the approved agencies can be found [here](http://down.mofa.go.kr/ph-en/brd/m_3277/down.do?brd_id=13950&seq=738690&data_tp=A&file_seq=1).

Alternatively you can [visit Jeju island visa-free](http://www.iccjeju.co.kr/EN/AboutJeju/AccessAndVisa).

Answer (score 0):

It is of course possible for you to apply, but if you don’t meet the eligibility criteria and cannot provide acceptable documents to demonstrate your personal and financial circumstances, the application is highly likely to be refused.